# error: 'varName' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opencv, declare

I want to find the biggerst contour in my image (with opencv and C++). I have been read this thread: 
[Finding Contours in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449378/finding-contours-in-opencv) and [Draw the biggest element conncted using areaContours (OpenCV )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154388/draw-the-biggest-element-conncted-using-areacontours-opencv) but I got error: 'varName' was not declared in this scope, which mean compiler think I haven't been declare that variable right? So this snippet of my code:

```
    threshold(Img, Img, t, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    vector<vector<Point>> varName;
    findContours(Img, varName, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

I got this error:

```
   D:\OpencvWorkspace\....|50|error: 'varName' was not declared in this scope|
```

Line 50 is this code:

```
    vector<vector<Point>> varName;
```

My question. Why compiler ask this variable haven't declare at the line I declare that variable. could someone help me?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you using  a pre- C++11 standard compiler? Try `vector<vector<Point> >` (note the space).

Comment: sorry because I think the source of the problem is on that line. thanks @chris for reminding me. :)

Comment: I check it version GCC 4.6.2. I don't know it is same with pre-C++11 standar compiler or different.. But yups.. It work for me. Problem because little space. Thanks @πάνταῥεῖ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used a pre c++11 standard compiler (as proven in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329860/error-varname-was-not-declared-in-this-scope#comment46849565_29329860)). The older standard had a problem letting the parser disambiguate a pair of closing angle brackets `>>` used in a nested template type specifier, from the `operator>>()`. Thus you had to write a space between them:

```
vector<vector<Point> > varName;
                 // ^ Note the space
```

Answer (score 0):

Yups like πάντα ῥεῖ say. the problem because space between ">" and ">".
so I change the declaration from this:

```
   vector<vector<Point>> varName;
```

to this one:

```
   vector<vector<Point> > varName;
```

By adding space between ">" and ">" and the errror is gone.. Thanks πάντα ῥεῖ