# Double closing angle brackets (>>) generates syntax error

Tags: c++, eclipse, templates, c++11, language-lawyer

Eclipse (Luna, 4.4.2) tells me that I have a syntax error on the following line:

```
static_cast<Vec<int, DIM>>(a.mul(b));
```

I remembered that double closing angle brackets `>>` can lead to problems with some compilers, so I put a blank in between: `> >`. The syntax error disappears.

However, I have many `>>` in my program where no syntax error is detected, such as:

```
Node<Element<DIM>> * e= a.get();
```

Why do I get an error the above mentioned specific case? This is related to [error: 'varName' was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329860/error-varname-was-not-declared-in-this-scope), but I don't know why my compiler does accept a `>>` sometimes, but not always.

Comment: _"This is NOT a duplicate"_ I well explained the c++ parser ambiguity with the `operator>>()` for pre c++11 standard compilers. `>>>` doesn't fall into that parsing case, thus it works.

Comment: Ok, i removed the `>>>` case which is misleading. But there are still several `>>` cases in my program which do not lead to a syntax error. Your post does not say anything whether `>>` does lead to problems in any or in specific cases, and that's what I'm wondering about.

Comment: The asterisk `*` could also make well a difference for the parser. Essentially it boils down to that mentioned ambiguity with `operator>>`.

Comment: Better use a space between closing brackets, if you don't want to get the compiler to get confused with the shift operator `>>`, thus `> >`...

Comment: @Michael I have to agree your question is better by means of a more canonical way to ask about the problem. Upvoted.

Comment: @CommuSoft That's for old compilers as mentioned.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: true, but for backwards compatibility, I think it is better to write it anyway...

Comment: @CommuSoft Well, if you need to have your code being backwards compatible, yes. But I have lots of code which already uses other current standard features like `std::array<>` etc. So I'm not bothering anymore about it, in preference of improved readability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have used a pre c++11 standard compiler. The older standard had a problem letting the parser disambiguate a pair of closing angle brackets `>>` used in a nested template type specifier, from the `operator>>()`. Thus you had to write a space between them.

The samples like `>>>` or `>>*` are falling under a different case for the old parsers, thus they work without error message.

---

<sub>I have to admit, I don't actually know what exactly was done in the c++11 (the current) standards definitions, that this situation can be clearly disambiguated by a c++11 compliant parser.</sub>

Comment: I'm not really convinced. It's the same problem in all three cases - maximum munch means that `>>` is being parsed as one token, not two. Perhaps the problem is with the second `>` not actually closing a template argument list in the first case (it closes the `static_cast` instead), but it's hard to tell without extra testing.

Comment: @T.C. Well, you have a good point. I'm not even sure either. The OP's use cases seem to improve the answer, that it's basically about an ambiguity with `operator>>()`. Could even be compiler implementation dependent. I'm eager to see, **how** the c++11 standard actually fixed this (added the [tag:language-lawyer] tag).

Comment: The fix is in [N1757](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1757.html). The construct is perfectly valid in C++11; the problem is definitely with the parser used by the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

The "right angle bracket fix" is found in §14.2 [temp.names]/p3 (emphasis mine):

> When parsing a *template-argument-list*, the first non-nested `>` is
>   taken as the ending delimiter rather than a greater-than operator.
>   **Similarly, the first non-nested `>>` is treated as two consecutive but
>   distinct `>` tokens, the first of which is taken as the end of the
>   *template-argument-list* and completes the
>   *template-id*. [ *Note*: The second `>` token produced by this replacement rule may terminate an enclosing
>   *template-id* construct or it may be part of a different construct (e.g. a cast).—*end note* ]**

If the `static_cast` is otherwise valid, then both pieces of code in the OP are perfectly valid in C++11 and perfectly invalid in C++03. If your IDE reports an error on one but not the other, then it's a bug with that IDE.

It's difficult (and also somewhat pointless) for us to speculate on the source of the bug. A potential cause can be that the second `>` are closing different constructs (the first case it's closing a cast, the second is closing a template argument list) and the parser's implementation somehow missed the "second `>` being part of a different construct" case. But that's just wild speculation.