# Can we define a 2D matrix of fixed width using std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I use the following example to illustrate my question:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > abc;
abc.push_back(std::vector<int>(9,0));
abc.push_back(std::vector<int>(9,2));
...
abc.push_back(std::vector<int>(9,20));
```

As you can see from the example each time a vector is put in the 2D vector, its dimension is the same. Variable `abc` represents a matrix of fixed width, and its height may increase or decrease based on the requirement. Therefore, I want to define something like `std::vector<std::vector(with fixed size)>`. How can I do it?

Comment: Is `fixed size` available at compile time?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, it is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the width of the matrix is known at compile time, you can use a vector of [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)s:

```
std::vector<std::array<int,10>> matNby10;
```

Now the width of the matrix is controlled by the array, which has fixed size. Other than that, it is nearly a drop-in replacement for a vector-of-vectors, as long as you do not try expanding row width.

Moreover, there is a decent chance that this approach would be more cache-friendly, because arrays would be stored next to each other inside the vector.

Comment: There should be a space in ">>". It should be `std::vector<std::array<int,10> > matNby10;`. Else you'll get a [compile time error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331315/double-closing-angle-brackets-generate-syntax-error-in-specific-case).

Comment: @athul.sure that's true, but only if you use ancient compilers. Starting with C++11 language parsers are required to handle this case properly.

Comment: True. But please specify it in the answer. If you compile the above code in g++ with no `std` flag, you'll get an error.

Comment: @athul.sure `std::array` is not available prior C++11, so OP would not be able to use this solution with an older compiler anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have underlying std::vector you can write custom wrapper like this:

```
template <typename T, int N>
struct vec 
{
    vec() 
        : _c {std::vector<T>(N)}
    {
    }

    vec(int default_val) 
        : _c {std::vector<T>(N, default_val)}
    {
    }

    T const& operator[](int index) const
    {
        return _c[index];
    }

    std::vector<T>& container() { return _c; }

private:
    std::vector<T> _c;
};
```

And you end up with this:

```
std::vector<vec<int,10>> asd;
```