# InputValidator for json - GCC compilation fail

Tags: c++, json, validation, templates

I am using [nlohmann json library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) which has `json::get<>()` function to get the value out of json with type checking. It throws an exception when there is a type mismatch. In my project I need a input json validation (if all the objects are there including correct types) so I built something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"

using namespace nlohmann;

template<typename _Tp>
class ValidatorField
{
public:
    using type = _Tp;

    ValidatorField(const std::string& tp) : fieldName(tp) {}
    const std::string& getName() const { return fieldName; }

private:
    std::string fieldName;
};

using string_t = ValidatorField<std::string>;
using int_t = ValidatorField<int>;
using bool_t = ValidatorField<bool>;

template<std::size_t N, class... _Ts>
static inline std::enable_if_t<N==0, bool> typeCheck(const json& j, const std::tuple<_Ts...>& tuple) noexcept
{
    try
    {
        if (j.find(std::get<N>(tuple).getName()) != j.end())
        {
            j[std::get<N>(tuple).getName()].get<std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<_Ts...>>::type>();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

template<std::size_t N, class... _Ts>
static inline std::enable_if_t < 0 < N, bool > typeCheck(const json& j, const std::tuple<_Ts...>& tuple) noexcept
{
    try
    {
        if (j.find(std::get<N>(tuple).getName()) != j.end())
        {
            j[std::get<N>(tuple).getName()].get<std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<_Ts...>>::type>();
            return typeCheck<N-1>(j, tuple);
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

class object_t
{
public:
    template<typename... _Ts>
    object_t(const std::string& tp, const std::tuple<_Ts...>& fields, const json& j) : fieldName(tp)
    {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << typeCheck<std::tuple_size_v<std::tuple<_Ts...>> - 1, _Ts...>(j, fields) << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::string fieldName;
};

int main()
{
    json j = json::object();
    j["field1"] = "strValue";
    j["field2"] = 4;
    j["field3"] = 4;
    std::cout << j.dump(4) << std::endl;

    object_t("branch", std::make_tuple(
        string_t {"field1"},
        int_t {"field2"},
        int_t {"field3"}
    ), j);
}
```

which works surprisingly well - except only on clang.
Example output:

```
{
    "field1": "strValue",
    "field2": 4,
    "field3": 4
}
true
```

I've tried compiling it with GCC - which yielded the following result:
[image]
Any ideas why am I seeing such behavior?

**EDIT 1**:
If I remove the content between [] braces, it works just fine. Also if I replace the `[std::get<N>(tuple).getName()]` with `["const-string"]` it works as well.
I'd lean towards the possibility that this is a bug in the GCC

Comment: Show your full compile command line, including C++ version used. That `>>` in the templates might be choking a pre-2011 standard version. If you have a build problem, you should always explain precisely how you build so people can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double closing angle brackets (>>) generate syntax error in SPECIFIC case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331315/double-closing-angle-brackets-generate-syntax-error-in-specific-case)

Comment: @underscore_d check the updated question. The version is 8.3.0. I suppose 
 the link does not answer my question.

Comment: `std::tuple_element_t` already is a type. Why are you trying to get its `::type`? That shouldn't ever work. Also, you lookup in the map twice, once by `find()` and once by `operator[]`, which is extremely wasteful; you should instead simply retain the returned iterator to the found item and call `->get()` on that.

Comment: @underscore_d it's type refer to template class's `using type = _Tp` regarding your second point you're right on this one. Furthermore, I've already rewritten the code (workaround) to work with GCC as well. Anyway, thank you for your help

Comment: No, what I mean is that `std::tuple_element_t<Foo>` is a template typedef alias that gets `std::tuple_element<Foo>::type`, so it should never compile in any compiler to write `std::tuple_element_t<Foo>::type`. What was your workaround?

Comment: @underscore_d you still don't get it. `std::tuple_element_t<>` returns an Nth type 
of the tuple **on which** `::type` is called, essentially having the same meaning as `Foo::type`. I will refrain from further comments for now.